# User Control Dependency Property Updating Multiple control values

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a feeling my base issue with this problem is binding some internal properties.

In the usercontrol I have a rectangle that contains a linear gradient. I created a dependency property to be able to give a value (0 to 1) to specify where the gradient line should be in the rectangle. To adjust this value dynamically I connected a slider to it for testing.

I also added some feedback textblocks to let me know how some of the data is flowing and if it is flowing. And from that I can tell my binding to my GradientStops.offset values from my user control properties  are not working. How do I get the user control to update the rectangle gradient by just changing RectangleLevel.RectLevel value?

**USERCONTROL XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="RectDynamicGradient.RectangleLevel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RectDynamicGradient"
             xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="180" d:DesignWidth="80">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="Cyan" Offset="{Binding Gradient_top_color, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="{Binding Gradient_bottom_color, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**USERCONTROL CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace RectDynamicGradient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for RectangleLevel.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class RectangleLevel : UserControl
    {
        public double Gradient_bottom_color { get; set; }

        public double Gradient_top_color { get; set; }

        public double RectLevel
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(RectLevelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RectLevelProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RectLevel.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RectLevelProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("RectLevel", typeof(double), typeof(RectangleLevel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, 
                new PropertyChangedCallback(ChangeLevel), 
                new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceLevel)), 
                new ValidateValueCallback(ValidateLevel));

        public static void ChangeLevel(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RectangleLevel t = d as RectangleLevel;
            t.UpdateGradientStops((double)e.NewValue);
        }
        public static object CoerceLevel(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            if (value is string valstring)
            {
                if (Double.TryParse(valstring, out double lvl))
                {
                    return lvl;
                }
            }
            if (value is double valdouble)
            {
                return valdouble;
            }
            throw new Exception();

        }
        public static bool ValidateLevel(object value)
        {
            double? level = 0;
            if (value is string valstring)
            {
                if (Double.TryParse(valstring, out double lvl))
                {
                    level = lvl;
                }
            }
            if (value is double valdouble)
            {
                level = valdouble;
            }

            if (level.HasValue && level >= 0 && level <= 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public RectangleLevel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void UpdateGradientStops(double level)
        {
            double scale = 0;

            if (level < .5)
            {
                scale = level;
            }
            else if (level >= .5)
            {
                scale = 1 - level;
            }

            Gradient_top_color = level;
            Gradient_bottom_color = level + (level * .1 * scale);
        }
    }
}
```

**MAINWINDOW XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="RectDynamicGradient.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RectDynamicGradient"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Slider x:Name="TheSlider" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Center" LargeChange="0.1" Maximum="1" SmallChange="0.01" >
            <Slider.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="2"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="2"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Slider.RenderTransform>
        </Slider>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock Text="SliderValue:"/>
                <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" Text="{Binding ElementName=TheSlider, Path=Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Text="UC LEVEL Value:"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=RectLevel}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <local:RectangleLevel x:Name="MyUserControl" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RectLevel="{Binding ElementName=TheSlider, Path=Value}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MAINWINDOW CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace RectDynamicGradient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, you could greatly improve the readability of your question if you would adhere to widely accepted naming conventions. Use PascalCasing for class and property names. Do not use underlines in names at all.

Comment: I was throwing together a quick example and pasting what I had.  The naming convention should be more standardized now.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

After feedback from the comments the improvments were made.

- DataContext removed this and added relative source to user control (named "uc")
- Changed NotifyProperties into DependencyProperties

**Replaced DataContext**

```
<GradientStop Color="Cyan" Offset="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=GradientFilledColor}"/>
```

**Updated Dependency Properties**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Property to change the GradientEmptyColor (GradientStop offset) of the rectangle by interfacing with the dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public double GradientEmptyColor
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(GradientEmptyColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GradientEmptyColorProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GradientEmptyColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GradientEmptyColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GradientEmptyColor", typeof(double), typeof(RectangleLevel), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));


    /// <summary>
    /// Property to change the GradientFilledColor (GradientStop offset) of the rectangle by interfacing with the dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public double GradientFilledColor
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(GradientFilledColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GradientFilledColorProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GradientFilledColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GradientFilledColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GradientFilledColor", typeof(double), typeof(RectangleLevel), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
```

The DependencyProperty provides the same capability as the INotifyProperty PropertChanged event (uses a different mechanism though).
As mentioned by @Clemens setting datacontext to self is a terrible idea and would break linking when the user control is used through-out the project and datacontext is set to something else.

I am still open to suggestions that help support good practices and learning.

**UPDATED CODE**

**USERCONTROL XAML**

```
    <UserControl x:Class="RectDynamicGradient.RectangleLevel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RectDynamicGradient"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="180" d:DesignWidth="80" x:Name="uc">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".5,1" EndPoint=".5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Cyan" Offset="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=GradientFilledColor}"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=GradientEmptyColor}"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**USERCONTROL CODE**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace RectDynamicGradient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for RectangleLevel.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class RectangleLevel : UserControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Property to change the GradientEmptyColor (GradientStop offset) of the rectangle by interfacing with the dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public double GradientEmptyColor
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(GradientEmptyColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GradientEmptyColorProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GradientEmptyColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GradientEmptyColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GradientEmptyColor", typeof(double), typeof(RectangleLevel), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));


        /// <summary>
        /// Property to change the GradientFilledColor (GradientStop offset) of the rectangle by interfacing with the dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public double GradientFilledColor
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(GradientFilledColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GradientFilledColorProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GradientFilledColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GradientFilledColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GradientFilledColor", typeof(double), typeof(RectangleLevel), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));


        /// <summary>
        /// Property to change the level (GradientStop offsets) of the rectangle by interfacing with the dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public double RectLevel
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(RectLevelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RectLevelProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RectLevel.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RectLevelProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("RectLevel", typeof(double), typeof(RectangleLevel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, 
                new PropertyChangedCallback(ChangeLevel), 
                new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceLevel)), 
                new ValidateValueCallback(ValidateLevel));

        /// <summary>
        /// PropertyChangedCallback for DependencyProperty RectLevelProperty.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">Dependency object causing the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Change event arguments.</param>
        public static void ChangeLevel(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RectangleLevel t = d as RectangleLevel;
            t.UpdateGradientStops((double)e.NewValue);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// CoerceValueCallback for DependencyProperty RectLevelProperty.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">Dependency object causing the event.</param>
        /// <param name="value">Value being sent to RectLevelProperty be coerced.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static object CoerceLevel(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            if (value is string valstring)
            {
                if (Double.TryParse(valstring, out double lvl))
                {
                    return lvl;
                }
            }
            if (value is double valdouble)
            {
                return valdouble;
            }
            throw new Exception();

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// ValidateValueCallback for DependencyProperty RectLevelProperty
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Value being sent to RectLevelProperty be validated.</param>
        /// <returns>True, if valid value between and including 0 and 1.</returns>
        public static bool ValidateLevel(object value)
        {
            double? level = 0;
            if (value is string valstring)
            {
                if (Double.TryParse(valstring, out double lvl))
                {
                    level = lvl;
                }
            }
            if (value is double valdouble)
            {
                level = valdouble;
            }

            if (level.HasValue && level >= 0 && level <= 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor sets DataContext to itself.
        /// </summary>
        public RectangleLevel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the variables binded to the GradientStops for the rectangle.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="level">Level where the GradientStops should be. Valid value is 0 to 1 representing 0 to 100% filled.</param>
        private void UpdateGradientStops(double level)
        {
            double scale = 0;

            if (level < .5)
            {
                scale = level;
            }
            else if (level >= .5)
            {
                scale = 1 - level;
            }

            GradientFilledColor = level;
            GradientEmptyColor = level + (level * .1 * scale);
        }
    }
}
```

**MAINWINDOW XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="RectDynamicGradient.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RectDynamicGradient"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Slider x:Name="TheSlider" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Center" LargeChange="0.1" Maximum="1" SmallChange="0.01" >
            <Slider.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="2"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="2"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Slider.RenderTransform>
        </Slider>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock Text="SliderValue:"/>
                <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" Text="{Binding ElementName=TheSlider, Path=Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Text="UC LEVEL Value:"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=RectLevel}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <local:RectangleLevel x:Name="MyUserControl" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RectLevel="{Binding ElementName=TheSlider, Path=Value}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Be aware that explicitly setting the own DataContext in a UserControl is a common mistake. It breaks any DataContext-based Bindings of the dependency properties of the control. Implementing INPC is also pointless, since all properties could simply be dependency properties, which have their own notification mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I didn't know DependencyProperty provided the  OnPropertyChanged event. It must happen during the register method and all the magic behind the scenes. Thanks for your feedback and pointers!

Comment: It's a different mechanism than INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Again thanks for your assistance Clemens. I spent time debating on if I should push this at all, but I figured it would be selfish of me to take information and not try to share solutions. I thought my question was valid and my solution solved the problem. right now other beginners such as myself will think the question is trash when I think it provides a helpful solution. If there is something someone thought was unsatisfactory please let me know to resolve the discrepancies and we can help others together.